Can I append tags from one sheet to the a column in another sheet based on conditions?
Refer to this file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tVuhFYKXCFXjYTVncfOW79uBo55qhEI6BhdUOkZegOU/edit#gid=79825211
The first sheet has shopify export of my product which has a product handle in column A and tags in column G. The second sheet is a list of handles and tags.
Now I want to check against sheet 2 if the handle is present in sheet 1, append the tag of that row in sheet 1 against the same handle.
for eg, if handle carbon-fiber-antenna is present in sheet 1's handle column, then the tag 20071 SeriesE81 will be added to tags already present in sheet 1 like: interir, exterior, 20071 SeriesE81
The main motive is to add tags to all products so I can import it back to shopify.
I am not able to think of anything

Try This, It will update the "Tags" column (G) in Sheet 1 with the original tags appended with any matching tags from Sheet 2. For handles not found in Sheet 2, the original tags remain unchanged.
=CONCATENATE(G2:G,", ",XLOOKUP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,", "))


Put this formula in cell products_export_1 (12)!BC1:
=map(A2:A, G2:G, lambda(handle, tags, 
  if(len(handle) * len(tags), 
    let( 
      newTags, filter( 
        k!B$2:B, 
        len(k!A$2:A), 
        k!A$2:A = handle, 
        iserror(search(", " & k!B$2:B & ",", ", " & G2 & ",")) 
      ), 
      textjoin(", ", true, tags, ifna(newTags)) 
    ), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
))

You can then overwrite the original tags in column G2:G with these augmented values using Edit > Paste special > Paste values only and remove the formula.
